# Sqlite pendingOperation in Statement prepare

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, java-me

My code is:

```
Statement mstatement = null;
URI uri = URI.create(DBPath);
sqliteDb = DatabaseFactory.openOrCreate(uri);

mStatement = sqliteDb.createStatement(strQuery);
mStatement.prepare();
```

My problem is, I am getting error as "Sqlite pendingOperation" at mstatement.prepare();.
I am using synchronized blocks at each and every database handling methods. This is happening while multiple threads are running.

Comment: Can you include the entire exception message?  Also, including the actual string that appears in 'strQuery' will be helpful.

Comment: My query is: 
SELECT EventId,OldTitle,OrderNumber,Status,Title,Type,UpdateDateTime,Id FROM Questions WHERE EventId=5 AND Type=1 AND (Status=0 OR Status=1 OR Status=2) ORDER BY OrderNumber

Error is: SqlitependingOperation

Comment: @AnkitRox: Please add more code to your sample. This would include setting `strQuery`, and more. Also, as Michal Donohue said, please include the full error message, ideally include the stack trace.

Comment: Hi  sixfeetsix: I have added my comment as answer, please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got my answer by myself.

**I modified all method as(in bold):**

```
Cursor c = null;
DBHelper.mStatement = null;
Vector followups = new Vector();
**boolean runFlag = true;**
synchronized (GlobalVariables.lockObject) {
try {
**while(runFlag)**
SELECT EventId,OldTitle,OrderNumber,Status,Title,Type,UpdateDateTime,Id FROM Questions WHERE EventId=5 AND Type=1 AND (Status=0 OR Status=1 OR Status=2) ORDER BY OrderNumber 

                DBHelper.CreateAndOpenSqliteDBConnection();
DBHelper.mStatement = DBHelper.sqliteDb.createStatement(strQuery);
DBHelper.mStatement.prepare();

**if(DBHelper.mStatement == null)
    {
        DBHelper.CloseSqliteDBConnection();
                        runFlag = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        runFlag = false;
                    }**

c = DBHelper.mStatement.getCursor();

while (c.next()) {
                    followups.addElement(Followup.getFromCursor(c));
                }
}
**}**
catch (Exception ex) {
System.out.print(ERRORSTRING + "getUploadFollowupsFromDB: "
                        + ex);
} finally {

DBHelper.CloseSqliteDBConnection();
}
GlobalVariables.lockObject.notifyAll();
}
return followups;
```

***Great Ankit Rox..***

Comment: `boolean runFlag` would better be declared as volatile (check multithreading Java tutorials if you're interested why is that)

Comment: But what is the need to make it volatile.

Comment: to guarantee that updates made to it from other threads will have effect

Comment: Not needed, because there are synchronized blocks and at the single unit of time, one thread will enter into block and **runFlag** is individual for each and every execution of block.

Comment: so, you read/write `runFlag` only within synchronized blocks right? in that case it's indeed OK without volatile

Comment: ok, that's why I am just using it simply without making it volatile.